# XDocument Class in VB.NET

Tags: wpf, xml, vb.net, silverlight

I am learning Silverlight and WPF on my own to expand my programming base. I am following [this tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-1-creating-quot-hello-world-quot-with-silverlight-2-and-vs-2008.aspx), and I am currently stuck on [part 3](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-3-using-networking-to-retrieve-data-and-populate-a-datagrid.aspx). I am up to the point where my application requests and receives a response from Digg, but I cannot figure out how to properly dimension the `XDocument` class (as the tutorial shows) to read the xmlcontent that is retrieved.

Granted, the tutorial is in C# (which I know very little about), but I do not see why I cannot access this class. IntelliSense suggested replacing `XDocument` with `Document.Run`, but that got me nowhere. I also read that this class was part of the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace, but even trying to dimension my variable as

> `Dim xS as System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`

Gives me nothing. Anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly you need to add the System.Xml.Linq dll in the project references.

Answer (score 1):

What version of .Net/Visual Studio are you using?  XDocument wasn't added to the framework until .Net 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

As the above posters mentioned Linq is a .Net 3.5 addition.

I had a very similar problem recently trying to used linq features in what I thought was a 3.5 enabled app but my web.config was from an older project.

If you know you have 3.5 installed, try making a new project and add your code back into it.